# Review code changes by a single contributor?

Tags: git

I realize the best way to manage code reviews is with pull requests. However for reviewing history, I want to be able to review the changes of a single contributor over a period of time; where all the commits are mixed into master already.

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using a provider, such as GitHub, which might have its own set of tools for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Commit Limiting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_limiting) section of the `git log` documentation.

To filter the **who**:

> ```
> --author=<pattern>
> --committer=<pattern>
> ```
>
> Limit the commits output to ones with author/committer header lines that match the specified pattern (regular expression). With more than one --author=, commits whose author matches any of the given patterns are chosen (similarly for multiple --committer=).

To filter the **when**:

> ```
> --since=<date>
> --after=<date>
> ```
>
> Show commits more recent than a specific date.
>
> ```
> --until=<date>
> --before=<date>
> ```
>
> Show commits older than a specific date.

This used together with the `-p` and you get all the information you might want

> ```
> -p
> -u
> --patch
> ```
>
> Generate patch (see section on generating patches).